# combining string data of 3 tables into a single table procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, concatenation, procedure

I have three tables with similar table structure:

table_A(**userId, month, year**, some_text)
table_B(**userId, month, year**, some_text)
table_C(**userId, month, year**, some_text)

some_text is a column that can contain string values such as Alpha, Beta, Gamma

Requirement: I need to create a procedure that will combine (concat) some_text value of each (userId, month, year) into one.

Here's an example:

```
table_A(1, 'JAN', 2022, 'Alpha')
table_B(1, 'JAN', 2022, 'Beta')
table_C(1, 'JAN', 2022, 'Gamma')
table_C(2, 'JAN', 2022, 'Gamma')
```

Combining the above data into another table called table_X would look like this:

```
table_X(**userId, month, year**, some_text):
(1, 'JAN', 2022, '[Alpha, Beta, Gamma]')
(2, 'JAN', 2022, '[Gamma]')
```

As mentioned above, the first row in the target table contains concatenated values of `some_text` column from table_A, table_B and table_C.

The second row contains only "[Gamma]" since there was only one row given for that particular (userId, month, year).

How can I achieve the above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

you can use union all to combine 3 tables refer : [https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php#:~:text=The%20MySQL%20UNION%20ALL%20operator%20is%20used%20to%20combine%20the,between%20the%20various%20SELECT%20statements](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php#:%7E:text=The%20MySQL%20UNION%20ALL%20operator%20is%20used%20to%20combine%20the,between%20the%20various%20SELECT%20statements).

syntax :

```html
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions]
UNION ALL
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions];
```

Comment: No, union isn't what I'm looking for. What I'm trying is to get it inserted in table_X along with some_text column containing concatenated data. If you look at my question, I have mentioned that (userId, month and year) is a composite primary key. So `some_text` column from table_X should contain the concatenated result.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The below query would work.

**To create Table_X:**

```
create table Table_X(userid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,month varchar(5),year varchar(5),some_txt varchar(50));
```

**To add data to it with above condition:**

```
 insert into Table_X (select userid, month, year, GROUP_CONCAT (some_txt ) as some_txt from (select * from Table_A UNION ALL select from Table_B UNION ALL select * from Table_C) group by userid, month, year);
```